# i am getting server error while calling post method in my api using batch file

Tags: django

I am getting right result using both methods when i running my manage.py script through pycharm, but when i am running it through batch file, then i am getting server error 500 for post method.

This is my batch file-

@echo off
cd F:/hash/hashtaggenerator/
set "VIRTUAL_ENV=F:\hash\env"

if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT (
set "PROMPT=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT%"
) else (
if not defined PROMPT (
set "PROMPT=$P$G"
)
if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=%PROMPT%"
)
)
if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
if "" NEQ "" (
set "PROMPT=() %PROMPT%"
) else (
for %%d in ("%VIRTUAL_ENV%") do set "PROMPT=(%%~nxd) %PROMPT%"
)
)

REM Don't use () to avoid problems with them in %PATH%
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME goto ENDIFVHOME
set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONHOME%"
:ENDIFVHOME

set PYTHONHOME=

REM if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH (
if not defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH1
set "PATH=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH1
REM ) else (
if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH2
set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=%PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH2

set "PATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts;%PATH%"

F:/hash/env/Scripts/python.exe manage.py runserver ip address:4321
pause

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are running a batch file with forward slashes as path separators, but lets set that aside for a minute. It sounds like maybe PyCharm is not using the same virtual environment as the batch file. Try doing a pip freeze command in the PyCharm terminal and comparing it to the same command in the terminal you get when you run *F:/hash/env/Scripts/activate.bat* (or on a default cmd.exe environment *F:\hash\env\Scripts\activate.bat*). With any luck, it's a simple issue of pip installing a module that is installed in the PyCharm environment but not your F:/hash/env environment.